# SHA hash doesn't match

Tags: tor-install

I have downloaded Tor for Windows (torbrowser-install-6.0.6_en-US.exe) and ran SHA256 hash check in Powershell using the Get-FileHash command. The value is 4764401CE6B6E78D0CA000CA1271A507569C391D9518821DF3090513133CF567. The problem is that this value doesn't match with the value published in the "sha256sums-unsigned-build.txt" file at "https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.0.6/" which is 7c1782151e30b5b714927a9170e02db80ae1ed9f09c9f164e753d3c1e09c9d48.

Answer (score 0):

Not incredible, but possible case - I've helped a person who had a **fake tor.exe** in Tor Browser Bundle, and he stated that he had downloaded it from a Tor website. Re-download it again from a different network connection

Comment: Wrong. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: I've told what I saw myself - it was a fake binary mimicing tor output

Comment: Great but what you saw has absolutely nothing to do with what the user reported. Those checksums will never match for the reasons I outlined on my answer to the question that this is a duplicate of. Jumping to the conclusion of malice isn't helpful.